# Searching an IEnumerable<dynamic>

Tags: c#, search, dynamic, find

I have an enumerable as follows:

```
 IEnumerable<dynamic> collection = new 
 {  
    column1 = "1", column2 = "name", column3= "somevalue" 
 }, 
 new 
 { 
    column1 = "2",   column2 = "name2", column3= "somevalue2" 
 },
 new 
 { 
    column1 = "3", column2 = "name3", column3= "somevalue3" 
 }
```

and so on....The number of columns in the dynamic types can also vary.No of columns can be more or less.

Now if I want to search this IEnumerable collection for e.g. somevalue2, I need the following information
Found in Row 2 (Assume column1 is always primary key) in Column "column2".
Which would be the best way to translate this dynamic collection into a data structure (.NET List/Collection/Hashtable etc.) and the best way to query the information from the collection. The collection will at most will be a page of data (25 rows).
Any code snippets and data structures to do a  super fast efficient way of searching the data would be appreciated. Assume the search term is "contains" match as opposed to a perfect match.

Comment: "super fast" and "dynamic" do not usually appear in the same context :)

Comment: Must you have a sequence of `dynamic`s?  It seems like a sequence of string arrays would serve you much better.

Comment: This is the structure of the data and I have no control to alter it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are anonymous types; anonymous types are a compiler feature, so that layout is **fixed rigid** at compile time, so they aren't going to vary. I would suggest: don't use `dynamic`. For example:

```
 var arr = new[] {
   new { column1 = "1", column2 = "name", column3= "somevalue" }, 
   new { column1 = "2", column2 = "name2", column3= "somevalue2" },
   new { column1 = "3", column2 = "name3", column3= "somevalue3" }
 };
```

which is all strongly typed and well-defined. You can use regular operations, for example:

```
var item2 = arr.FirstOrDefault(x => x.column1 == "2");
```

again, all static-typed.

If you want to search all the columns, then I would suggest something like a dictionary is better:

```
 var arr = new[] {
   new Dictionary<string,string> { {"column1", "1"}, ... }, 
   new Dictionary<string,string> { {"column1", "2"}, ... }, 
   new Dictionary<string,string> { {"column1", "3"}, ... }, 
 };
```

Since you can then just look at `.Values.Contains(...)`

---

Edit: with the comment I *think* I understand it more clearly; I am picturing an opaque method that returns `IEnumerable<dynamic>` that are actually POCO types (not dynamic types) and we want to check the string members (arbitrary names) for a match. We should be able to do that with reflection, but [FastMember](http://nuget.org/packages/FastMember) will make it much faster:

```
static void Main()
{
    string search = "ame2";

    int rowIndex = 0;
    string[] names = null;
    TypeAccessor accessor = null;
    foreach(object row in GetData())
    {
        if(names == null)
        { // first row; get the property-names and build an accessor
            names = (from prop in row.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                     where prop.PropertyType == typeof (string)
                     select prop.Name).ToArray();
            accessor = TypeAccessor.Create(row.GetType());
        }

        foreach(var name in names)
        {
            var val = accessor[row, name] as string;
            if(val != null && val.Contains(search))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("row {0}, col {1}, val {2}", rowIndex, name, val);
            }
        }
        rowIndex++;
    }
}
static IEnumerable<dynamic> GetData()
{
    yield return new {column1 = "1", column2 = "name", column3 = "somevalue"};
    yield return new {column1 = "2", column2 = "name2", column3 = "somevalue2"};
    yield return new {column1 = "3", column2 = "name3", column3 = "somevalue3"};
}
```

Comment: My return type is IEnumerable<dynamic> and hence I cannot execute the code.

Comment: @chugh97 I suspect you may want to show that in a bit more context, i.e. in what way this is the return type, etc, and how the caller wants to use it. At the moment, the (lack of) context is very confusing.

Comment: If a user searches for a search term for e.g ACC01, then 25 rows of IEnumerable<dynamic> where dynamic is the underlying datatable say for this instance is 6 columns. ACC01 is searched within all 6 columns and all 25 rows. If a match is found the row with its row number and the column in which the data is found with the contains match is returned. For eg if the column in the 25 rows  has a column which is "My ACC No is ACC01020345", as AAC01 is contained in the string, the column name, row number and the value is retuned back to the user.

Comment: My return type is collection of dynamics as I have hundreds to tables using this same function and I have no control to change it.

Comment: Column names would be different in different table instances. So The code above is good except that dynamic object's properties could be different. Is it possible to make it very generic like looping thru the dynmaic's properties

Comment: @chugh97 hehe, nope. Cannot do. The problem with `dynamic` is that you absolutely **cannot** use reflection, because `dynamic` and reflection are the exact **opposite** of models. If the code is actually just `object`, of well-defined classes, then you **can** do it, but they arguably you shouldn't be saying it is `dynamic`. So: how `dynamic` is it... is it *actually* `dynamic` ? (i.e. could it be using `ExpandoObject` or similar underneath). Or is it just objects?

Comment: They are Plain OLD CLR Objects with Public properties

Comment: @chugh97 ok; and: is each set "homogeneous" ? i.e. within a single call, are all the objects of the same type?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15027/discussion-between-chugh97-and-marc-gravell)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exactly hides underneath your IEnumerable, but recently I had to search through results returned by Dapper from some query that were returned as IEnumerable of dynamic (which is how I came across this question).

In my case the solution was to cast my

```
IEnumerable<dynamic>
```

as

```
IEnumerable<IDictionary<String, Object>>
```

but I presume it's only going to work for data fetched thorugh dapper like:

```
db.Connection.Query(myQuery)
```

For this particular problem something like this might work (haven't tested):

```
IEnumerable<IDictionary<String, Object>> data = YourData.Cast<IDictionary<String, Object>>();
var row = data.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Where(y => y.Value.ToString() == "somevalue2"));
```

I have no idea how fast would this work, but I hope it'll help you (or someone, seeing that this question was posted a while ago).

Answer (score 0):

If you really want them to be dynamic objects with different columns in each item, you can declare it like this:

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> collection = new dynamic[]
                                        {
                                            new  
                                                {
                                                    column1 = "1",
                                                    column2 = "name",
                                                    column3 = "somevalue"
                                                },
                                            new
                                                {
                                                    column1 = "2",
                                                    column2 = "name2"
                                                },
                                            new
                                                {
                                                    column1 = "3",
                                                    column2 = "name3",
                                                    column3 = "somevalue3",
                                                    column4 = "fourthValue"
                                                }
                                        };
```

Converting it to a list is simple:

```
// create a list
var list = new List<dynamic>(collection);
```

Finding an item is a little more complex since the properties may not exist:

```
// find an item
var itemOne = collection.Where(i =>
                                    {
                                        try
                                        {
                                            if (i.column1 == "1")
                                            {
                                                return true;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        catch
                                        {
                                            // ignore error, column doesn't exist
                                        }
                                        return false;
                                    });
```